# Difficulty in finding open sets and boundary of set in subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

**Question:** let $X=\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{Q}$ with subspace topology of the usual topology on $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $P=\{(n,\frac{1}{n}): n∈\mathbb{N}\}$ then

(1) In the space $X$, $P$ is open or closed or both or neither?

(2) what is boundary of $P$ in $X$

i known open sets in $(X, τ)$ is of the form, $\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{Q}∩S$ where $S$ is open set in $\mathbb{R^2}$ but by the representation of $P$, I am unable to determine whether $P$ is of this form or not and further, upto yet I had only find boundary of sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology, But they are asking to find boundary of set in the subspace topology. please help me, stuck on it from hours..... :-(

Comment: Notice that $P$ is the graph of $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ via $f(n) = 1/n$. This is a countable collection of discrete points, and each point has distance $>1$ to all other points in $P$. The compliment to this set is trivially open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so $P$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$. On the other hand, $P$ cannot be open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (why?). What can you tell me now about whether $P$ is open, closed, or clopen in $X$?

Comment: @Joe sir, isn't we have to check in subspace topology, not in Euclidean topology?

Comment: Recall that $X$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in its usual topology. You gave a nice relationship between the subspace topology on $X$ and the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ above ...

Comment: @Joe sir, according to your comment what I get, $P$ is closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$ so that, $\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{Q}∩ P$ is closed in $X$ and it is nothing but $P$ itself. So $P$ is closed in $X$? Is am I correct?

Comment: Indeed! As for the boundary, I'm several years removed from point-set topology so I need to think more. Hopefully someone else will be able to help you more with that part. I'm inclined to believe that $\partial P = P$, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Thank you so much all of you, for giving your valuable time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P$ is closed in $X$. Consider $(n,q) \in X \setminus P$. Then $q \ne \frac1n$ so notice that $$B_X\left((n,q), \min\left\{\left|\frac1n - q\right|, 1\right\}\right) \subseteq X \setminus P$$

so $X \setminus P$ is open, therefore $P$ is closed.

$P$ is not open, for any $r > 0$ we have $$\left(1, 1+q\right) \in B_X(\underbrace{(1,1)}_{\in P}, r) \setminus P$$

where $q$ is a rational number in $\left\langle 0, \frac{r}2\right\rangle$.

The boundary $\partial P$ has to be a subset of $P$ since $P$ is closed. On the other hand, for every $\left(n, \frac1n\right) \in P$ and $r > 0$ we have that

$$\left(n, \frac1n+q\right) \in B_X\left(\left(n, \frac1n\right), r\right) \setminus P$$

where $q$ is a rational number in $\left\langle 0, \frac{r}2\right\rangle$. We conclude that $\partial P = P$.

Comment: Sir, I am trying to understand your answer sir, but facing difficulty in notations ...

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi $B(x, r)$ is the open ball centered at $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with radius $r > 0$. $B_X(x,r) = B(x,r) \cap X$ is the open ball in the space $X$. Recall that a set $S$ is open if for every point $x \in S$ there exists an open ball centered at $x$ contained in $S$. Also recall that $x \in \partial S$ if and only if every open ball centered at $x$ intersects both $S$ and $X \setminus S$.

Comment: Sir, the about definition of open set in your comment, is definiition of open set in usual topology on $\mathbb{R^2}$ Or am I wrong?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi It is the definition of an open set in any metric space. $S$ is open in $X$ if for every $x \in S$ there exists an open ball $B_X(x,r)$ in the space $X$ such that $B_X(x,r) \subseteq S$.

Comment: Sorry sir, I didn't notice "open ball **in $X$** :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is closed but not open and the boundary is empty.

Because any open ball $B(x,\delta)$ for a point $x\in X$  is of the form {n}$\times(\mathbb{Q}\cap(a,b))$, contains countably many points.
But any point $x\in P, x=(n,\frac{1}{n})$ the $B(x,\delta)$ contains only one point of P, the center itself, x is not an interior point of P and has no limit point. So P is closed but not open.

P has no interior, the boundary is P itself.

Comment: You are incorrect about the boundary.

Comment: yea got it, thanks